# How to get the div's name of same class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Here I have common children class names for 2 divs.By having these class names,how to find am in which parent div ?for ex. I want to get divTab1Btn or divTab2Btn.

```
<div id='divTab1Btn' class='tabBtn' style='display: block; visibility: visible;'>
 <input id='divTab1BtnEdit' class="btneditclick" classvalue="1" type='button' table2focus="tblAddtype" value='Edit' style='width: 75px; display: none; visibility: hidden;' />
 <input id='divTab1BtnConfirm' class="btnconfirm" gridid="1655" classvalue="1" type='button' value='Confirm' hdnheadergridlinkfield="ADD_MRECID" style='width: 85px; display: none; visibility: hidden;' />
      </div>


   <div id='divTab2Btn' class='tabBtn' style='display: block; visibility: visible;'>
 <input id='divTab1BtnEdit' class="btneditclick" classvalue="1" type='button' table2focus="tblAddtype" value='Edit' style='width: 75px; display: none; visibility: hidden;' />
 <input id='divTab1BtnConfirm' class="btnconfirm" gridid="1655" classvalue="1" type='button' value='Confirm' hdnheadergridlinkfield="ADD_MRECID" style='width: 85px; display: none; visibility: hidden;' />
      </div>
```

How to get the div's name of same class in jquery?

Comment: do you mean in a click handler for the button

Comment: inside click you can get like `$(this).parent().attr('id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( 'input[type=button]' ).click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `this` context refer to those two buttons `btneditclick` and `btnconfirm`:

```
 var divId = $(this).closest('.tabBtn').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$('.tabBtn').on('click', function(){ //<-- here if you click the div class name .tabBtn
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

If you click button inside class name tabBtn, then :

```
 $('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){ //<-- here if you click the button inside class name .tabBtn
  alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the id of div element on click of your buttons like:

```
$(".btneditclick").click(function(){
  var divId=$(this).parent("div").attr('id'); //this will return you the id of div,i.e. divTab1Btn or divTab2Btn
});
```